# Using `newtype` to wrap other types

Tags: haskell, newtype

I'm trying to understand `newtype` and thought this would work:

```
module NT where

newtype X = X Double
newtype Y = Y Double

doit :: X -> Y -> Double
doit x y = x + y

x = X 1.1
y = Y 2.2

-- doit x y should work
-- doit y x should error
```

The first error produced is:

```
NT.hs:7:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘X’
    • In the expression: X x + Y y
      In an equation for ‘doit’: doit x y = X x + Y y
  |
7 | doit x y = X x + Y y
  |
```

I get that the types don't match, I just don't understand how to get around it.  I thought wrapping `Double` like this could be used to prevent the mixup of `x` and `y` in `doit`.

Is this true, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to “unwrap” the newtype before `+` can work.

```
doit :: X -> Y -> Double
doit (X x) (Y y) = x + y
```

Here, I am using pattern matching to unwrap the `Double` inside each argument. Here, `x` and `y` are both `Double`, so you can just add them with `x + y`.

Comment: Oh, it seems so obvious now!!

Answer (score 4):

You unwrap the elements out of the data constructor with *pattern matching*:

```
doit :: X -> Y -> Double
doit (X x) (Y y) = x + y
```

Here the `x` and `y` are thus `Double`s, since the parameters the `X` and `Y` data constructor wrap are `Double`s as well.

Comment: Oh, it seems so obvious now!!